# Laravel difference between terminable middleware and after middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-middleware

[Larave middleware understanding source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware)

It is mentioned that, there are two types of middleware: Before and after. Before middleware is handled before the request is handled and after middleware is handled after the request is handled.

But the function of terminable middleware is exact same as after middleware. Then what is the core difference between these two? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Terminable Middleware` runs after the response is ready and prepared.

`After Middleware` runs after the request but before the response is prepared.

So for example let's say you want to set a response header on all or a group of your responses, you can do so by using an after middleware. Because you need to set the header after you render the request but before you return the response.
However if you want to store the session data in storage, you can use terminable middlware.

This is the terminate method in `TerminableInterface`:

```
/**
 * Terminates a request/response cycle.
 *
 * Should be called after sending the response and before shutting down the kernel.
 */
public function terminate(Request $request, Response $response);
```

You receive the request and response object in the terminate method of Terminable middleware, but changing the response would not take effect because the response has already been returned.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation @Farzin.

Comment: @Farzin will terminable middleware slow down the response to the browser? Say I'm calling an external API in terminable middleware will this slow down my response?

Answer (score 0):

This example should showcase exactly what happens and at which point you should execute certain code:

```php
class MyMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Here: Execute code "before" the response has been "built".
        // Changes here still have effects to your controller actions
        // and views for instance.
        $doStuffBeforeBuiltAndBeforeSent = 'abc';

        // Now, calling `$next($request)` will run a layer of the middleware chain.
        $response = $next($request);

        // Here: Execute code "after" the response has been "built"
        // but before it has been sent.
        $doStuffAfterBuiltAndBeforeSent = 'def';
        
        return $response;
    }

    public function terminate(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        // Here: execute code after the response has been "sent".
        // Put anything here that might take considerable time which you
        // don't need in the response, e.g.:
        // Logs, stats, external-API calls that don't require the response etc.
        //
        // Note: this requires PHP to run in FastCGI mode.
        $doStuffAfterBuiltAndSent = 'ghi';

        // Note: there are no return values here since the PHP response
        // has been sent already.
    }
}
```

Note that middlewares will always run in the following order, assuming the order of middlewares in the kernel is `[One, Two, Three]` (it resembles somewhat of a callback-hell structure):

- `MyMiddlewareOne::class   => run before-response code (before $next($request))`
- `MyMiddlewareTwo::class   => run before-response code`
- `MyMiddlewareThree::class => run before-response code`
- `MyMiddlewareThree::class => run after-response code (after $next($request))`
- `MyMiddlewareTwo::class   => run after-response code`
- `MyMiddlewareOne::class   => run after-response code`