# How to continue executing PHP controller after returning the HTTP Get request response and remove serialization of 'closure' is not allowed

Tags: php, laravel

There is a HTTP GET request made from angular frontend and that request is hitting our PHP controller. We are generating a reference number in controller and making some external API calls to prepare some data. I need the controller to return a response to the get request first with generated reference number and then continue doing other external API calls to prepare data. 
 `My question is how can I achieve returning the response first from controller and then continue with other logic in same controller.` 
 I have taken reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764150/laravel-5-send-a-response-first-then-process-request-in-controller)
but still controller function doesn't actually return response until the finally block completes.

```
try {
    return response("", 200);
} finally {
    // Controller logic here
}
```

**UPDATE**
I have function in a Controller from where I am trying to dispatch the job:

```
public function getCount(int $count)
    {
        $refID = sprintf('REFID%s%s', $count, time());
        GetCountJob::dispatch($refID, $count, $this->auth->user(), $this->Connection);
        return response(['data' => ['refID' => $refID,],], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

Then the **construct method** in Job :

```
 public function __construct(string $refID, int $count, User $user, ConnectionInterface $Connection)
    {
        $this->refID = $refID;
        $this->count = $count;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->Connection = $Connection;
    }
```

and **Handle method** where some background code will run which is not getting triggered and getting error `serialization of 'closure' is not allowed`.

```
 public function handle()
    {
        /* some backend code needs to run here */
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have to do it with Queues. The sequence will still be, dispatch the job (data processing) onto the queue for processing and return the response. This will be non-blocking.

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen , I tried creating a Job and trying to dispatch it from the controller but the handle() method of the job is not getting triggered. And it throwing me error `serialization of 'closure' is not allowed`.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code. Usually, this is due to an object being passed to a job with a closure function. You can't pass `$request` directly via dispatch for example.

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen , I have updated the question above.

Comment: So the issue could be in the two arguments passed ($user, $connection). Either $user or $connection contains a closure that can't be serialized. For passing the user I would recommend passing the `id` of the user and getting the user from DB in the job handle method.  As for the connection, I don't know what it might contain but try to get it inside the job handle method.

Comment: I would recommend commenting out $user and $connection and seeing if the handle method is reached. Iteratively add these arguments and you might find out the problematic argument.

Comment: Because the job runs in the background. It tries to serialize the arguments passed to it and when that argument contains a closure it fails (As closures aren't serializable)

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen , I have added these arguments in the Job Handle method and removed them from the parameter which I am passing to the Job. Now only two parameters are getting passed to Job from controller. `GetCountJob::dispatch($refID, $count);` Still the `Handle()` method is not getting the hit while debugging in local.

Comment: Only __construct() is getting the hit but the debug is not hitting handle() method.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a Queue for that. See the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#main-content).

Simple example:

```php
// Run `php artisan make:job`

use App\Jobs\ProcessDataJob;

public function yourControllerMethod()
{
    $referenceNumber = generateReferenceNumber();

    return response($referenceNumber, 200)


    // Dispatch the job for further processing
    ProcessDataJob::dispatch($referenceNumber);
}
```

Comment: I tried creating a Job and dispatching it but getting below error:<br> `method_exists(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "App\Jobs\GetDataJob" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide an autoloader to load the class definition`

Answer (score 0):

There is also a terminable middleware. Search it in the documentation [Laravel difference between terminable middleware and after middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079401/laravel-difference-between-terminable-middleware-and-after-middleware)